# Do I need multiple user accounts or can we work with single user across all staff desktops?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business

Can I buy a single user Google Drive business account and set it up on all our staff computers with a single account. Why do I need to buy multiple accounts if I can keep all the files in one place and people only need to open it from their computers using the same account and change or edit it as required and it syncs across all computers since its a single account they are using?

Or is it like only one desktop per account or won't work simultaneously?

Comment: Try looking into [G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com).

Answer (score 1):

Google accounts are intended to be used by single users. Sharing an account between multiple users could trigger some security thresholds and this could block the account due to suspicious activity.

Instead of using a single account for all the staff computers, you could buy a single G Suite account license and share the files with consumer/free accounts, just train your users to request to the G Suite account holder to create/upload/copy the new files in order to keep them safe as company-owned assets.

Answer (score 0):

One Google Drive Account will work fine on multiple computers. 
The reason you would have multiple accounts is for keeping some files private while sharing others.
The whole concept of sharing from Google Drive is built around each user having their own account and inviting other users to share or collaborate with them.

Another thing to consider is that if each user has there own android or IOS device they already have a dedicated account for Gmail email and Google Drive and it is preferred sometimes to make this main account the business email rather than having two or three or more Gmail email accounts (a business Gmail and a Personal and now the "Special Shared Google Drive Account" you are thinking of creating ) because the Gmail Accounts and the Drive Accounts are connected. Google makes it easy to switch accounts within the App but having switch all the time from business to personal to "The Shared Google Drive" is not really fun.

Another consideration is the more users the more potential for sync issues an conflicts...I would recommend not syncing more than five windows PC's with sync client. The rest can use www.drive.google.com on the web.

Another consideration is the internet bandwidth needed to upload and download all those files to multiple users. A solution like Dropbox does this with one account across your local network without going out to the internet. You just need to enable the LAN sync feature.

So maybe Dropbox would be a better route to go.